# Extend regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to find invoice numbers with a regex. The string has be longer than 3 char. It may contain signs like {., , /, _}, all numbers and it may contain one or two capital letters - those can stay alone or after each other. That is, what I'm currently trying, without success.

```
`([0-9-\.\\\/_]{,3})([A-Z]{0,2})?`
```

Here I have two examples, which should be matched:

`019S836/03717008`

`DR094255`

This should not be matched:

`DRF094255`

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: You might need to totally redesign the pattern. Can the letters appear at the end of string?

Comment: It can appear anywhere in the string, yes

Comment: You don't have to use regex for everything. Just iterate through possible character-strip-possibilities and check the rest against the regex you already have.

Comment: Then please share your updated pattern with your attempt to implement the new requirements. The current pattern is not pertinent here.

Comment: Thought about something like this `^[[0-9-\.\\\/_]{3,}[A-Z]{,2}][0-9]$`

Comment: Ok, a guess: `^(?!(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})[0-9A-Z.\\\/_-]{3,}$`? See https://regex101.com/r/EYzw6e/1

Comment: If one replaces {3} by {4}, it seems to work, thank you...

Comment: Ok, the only problem now is, that it also matches if there is no number. The string has to contain numbers. But I think, I can handle that....

Comment: @Jan021981 I added a condition requiring a digit  in the string to the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?!(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})(?=\D*\d)[0-9A-Z.\\\/_-]{3,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYzw6e/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location (i.e. from the start of string), there are three occurrences of any zero or more chars other than uppercase ASCII letters followed with one uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=\D*\d)` - there must be at least one digit in the string
- `[0-9A-Z.\\\/_-]{4,}` - four or more occurrences of digits, uppercase letters, `.`, `\`, `/`, `_` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.